# Совпадения в массиве

Tags: массивы, php

Есть массив вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Шлем [12] (x14)  VP
            [1] => Зачаровать Шлем
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 14
            [4] => VP
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Шлем [11]  F
            [1] => Зачаровать Шлем
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 
            [4] => F
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Шлем [11]  P
            [1] => Зачаровать Шлем
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 
            [4] => P
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Шлем [11]  P
            [1] => Зачаровать Шлем
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 
            [4] => P
        )
)
```

Индексы 1,2,4 это( Название,уровень и качество предмета),индекс 3 это кол-во, мне надо посчитать кол-во предметов у которых совпадает название,уровень и качество,и оставить в массиве только единное название данного предмета.Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную задачу!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да обычным перебором это делается:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $foo) {
    $hash = $foo[1].$foo[2].$foo[4];
    if(isset($new_array[$hash])) {
        $new_array[$hash]['count'] += $foo[3];
    }
    else {
        $new_array[$hash] = array(
            'item'  => $foo,
            'count' => $foo[3]
        );
    }
}
```

Пример: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/r0f-zd8